# Manually encrypting and decrypting cookie - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I'm new to rails and trying to encrypt and decrypt a cookie manually. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

The below code raises this error `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature`

```
require 'cgi'
require 'json'
require 'active_support'
 
def verify_and_decrypt_session_cookie(cookie, secret_key_base)
  cookie = CGI::unescape(cookie)
  salt          = 'encrypted cookie'
  signed_salt   = 'signed encrypted cookie'
  key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(secret_key_base, iterations: 1000)
  secret = key_generator.generate_key(salt)[0, ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len]
  sign_secret = key_generator.generate_key(signed_salt)
  encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret, serializer: JSON)

  encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie)
end

cookie = 'example123'
secret = 'Rails.application.secret_key_base'  

p verify_and_decrypt_session_cookie(cookie, secret)
```

Thanks

Comment: To what end? There are much easier ways to do it. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

Comment: @max it's part of a tutorial I'm following, I think the intention is to show how sessions are handled and stored securely. Thanks for the link I'll check it out. Shared my code to check if there was anything obvious / fundamental I'm missing.

Comment: Fair enough - one glaring issue with this code is that you're using the string literal `'Rails.application.secret_key_base'` instead of the actual secret key of the application.